# Regex validation with fluent validation ASP.NET Core WebApi

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

I'm working with WebApi project and have used fluent validation for validating the request.

Userbase Dto.

```
public class UserBaseDto
{    
    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("countryId")]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phoneNumber")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

UserRegister Dto.

```
public class RegisterDto : UserBaseDto
{
}
```

UserBaseDtoValidator.

```
public class UserBaseDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<UserBaseDto>
{
    public UserBaseDtoValidator()
    {            
        RuleFor(x => x.Email)
            .EmailAddress()
            .WithMessage("Please provide valid email");

        RuleFor(x => x.PhoneNumber)
            .MatchPhoneNumberRule()
            .WithMessage("Please provide valid phone number");
    }
}
```

`MatchPhoneNumberRule` is a custom validator

```
public static class CustomValidators
{
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string> MatchPhoneNumberRule<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
    {
        return ruleBuilder.SetValidator(new RegularExpressionValidator(@"((?:[0-9]\-?){6,14}[0-9]$)|((?:[0-9]\x20?){6,14}[0-9]$)"));
    }
}
```

Regex is accepting 6 to 14 digit phone number.

Here, I want to check validation for registration request. So, I have done something like:

```
public class RegisterDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<RegisterDto>
{
    public RegisterDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x).SetValidator(new UserBaseDtoValidator());
    }       
}
```

All other validations working fine. However, regex is working for lower limit but when I pass more than 14 digit, validation not getting triggered.

Same expression working with `RegularExpressionAttribute`

Answer (score 0):

`(?:[0-9]\-?){6,14}[0-9]$` means 6–14 digits plus one digit at the end of the string.

Just add the `^` sign at the start of pattern. `^(?:[0-9]\-?){6,14}[0-9]$` means exactly 6–14 digits plus one digit in the entire string.

While `$` matches with the end of string, `[0-9]$` matches with any string that ends with a digit. `^` matches with the start of string, so `^[0-9]` means any string that starts with a digit. `^[0-9$` matches with any string that contains exactly one digit.

Your full pattern should look like:

```cs
@"^((?:[0-9]\-?){6,14}[0-9])|((?:[0-9]\x20?){6,14}[0-9])$"
```

Comment: @HinaKhuman As I can see, your regexp detects 7-15 digits. If you need exactly 6-14 digits just remove `[0-9]` at the ends of both expressions. Or change `6,14` to `5,13`.

Comment: Nope, not working. Perhaps, issue with fluent validation!

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following pattern:

```
(^(?:[0-9]\-?){5,13}[0-9]$)|(^(?:[0-9]\x20?){5,13}[0-9]$)
```

Comment: This answer could/should be improved. Please edit it and add an explanation on how it solves the problem so the original poster and others learn what was wrong.